# performItemClick in another view

Tags: java, android

In my app i have two 10x10 grids which have different adapters. When i click on item on the first grid it should change graphic on both first and second grid.

```
battleField = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
battleField2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
battleField.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
battleField2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));
battleField2.setEnabled(false);
battleField.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(SendobjectActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ImageView img = (ImageView)view1;
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.trafiony1);                           
        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        battleField2.performItemClick(view2, position, id);

    }
});

battleField2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view2, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(SendobjectActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
        ImageView img2 = (ImageView)view2;
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.trafiony2);
    }
});
```

I implemented onItemClickListener for both grids. When an item on the first grid is clicked it's graphic changes and id like to call performItemClick method to do the same on second grid. Unfortunetly i dont know how to get view of my second grid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Delegate the job to separate method and in your `onClickListener` call these methods instead of doing the job directly. So for example instead of:

```
battleField2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view2, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(SendobjectActivity.this, "" + position,
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView)view2;
    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.trafiony2);
  }
});
```

do something like:

```
battleField2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view2, int position, long id) {
    doTheJob( parent, view2, position, id );
  }
});

protected void doTheJob(AdapterView<?> parent, View view2, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(SendobjectActivity.this, "" + position,
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView)view2;
    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.trafiony2);
}
```

and the same for other listener. Then if you need to do both jobs, just call corresponding methods.

Or (if possible) turn your listeners into one.

Comment: It didnt solve the problem, when i call battleField2.performItemClick(view2, position, id); in battleField.onItemClickListener it doesnt know what view2 is.

Comment: Of course it does not know, because `view2` is clicked view. So you need to rework your code a bit to reach right view. I just gave you idea how to structure the code - some additional work needs yet to be done